# Function window() from conio.h doesnt work

Tags: turbo-c++, conio

I'm using turbo c++ which launches DOSBox 0.74

I have the following program:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  clrscr();
  window(100, 100, 200, 200);
  textcolor(3);
  textbackground(6);

  cprintf("Hello world");

  getch();

  return 0;
}
```

It works and it's pretty same copy from 2 sites, except, it dont make the window.
`window (100, 100, 200, 200)` should make a window with coordinates (100, 100) and (200, 200) from top left corner, but it doesn't happen and text just printed at most top left corner. I didn't find anyone with same problem. Instead tutorial sites shows this example and even screenshots as working.

Did anyone met this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window()` function from `conio.h` only defines an active window on the **text** screen. The default screen will be the 80x25 text screen. The coordinates that you specified in `window(100, 100, 200, 200);` are offscreen, so no window got created.
Try this:

```
window(10, 7, 50, 19);
gotoxy(16, 7);
cputs("Hello World");
```

For a graphical HelloWorld program, you would need to include `graphics.h` and setup a graphics video mode using `detectgraph()`, `initgraph()`, ...